# Use ethers JS to deploy smart contract with constructors

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

I am using ethers JS to deploy a smart contract. My constructor, however consists of two structs.

This is solidity code,

```
struct struct1 {
    string str1;
    bool bool1;
```

}

```
 struct struct2 {
    uint256 integer1;
    uint256 integer2;
 }


constructor( Struct1 memory struct1,
        Struct2 memory struct2 ) ERC721A("", "") {....
```

This is how I tried to encode the instruction using ethers js

```
        const factory = new ContractFactory(ABI, ByteCode, Signer);
    let contract = await factory.deploy(
        ['Collection','true'],
        ['100000','2000'],
        {
            maxPriorityFeePerGas,
            gasLimit: 3000000,
            maxFeePerGas,
            nonce,
        }
    )
```

Can someone help, I have not seen a single example online explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would help to pass the structs as objects and not as arrays, something like this,

```
  let contract = await factory.deploy(
        {str1:'Collection',bool1:true},
        {integer1:100000,integer2: 2000},
        {
            maxPriorityFeePerGas,
            gasLimit: 3000000,
            maxFeePerGas,
            nonce,
        }
```

Hope it helps!